# TSQL - Add missing dates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, recursive-query, dateadd

I have a query that results in the table shown below:

```
select * from (select [iKey], [StartDate], [FirstFCDate] from (SELECT [iKey], min([Date]) as [FirstFCDate] from dbo.factFC group by [iKey]) as gp left outer join (select [StartDate], [Key] from dbo.iKeys) dw on gp.iKey = dw.[Key]) ft

Table1
 iKey    StartDate       FirstFCDate
 101     2017-01-13      2017-04-01
 52      2016-11-11      2017-04-01
 21      2017-02-23      2017-04-01
 19      2014-01-21      2017-05-01
 34      2016-08-18      2017-07-01
```

What I am trying to do is insert a row into my fact table ( a separate table called dbo.factProd) so that on that table there is a row for every Date between the start date and the FirstFCDate.

Currently, my fact table looks like this:

```
 factProd
 ID     iKey    Date           pAmount   fcKey
 1      101      2017-04-01     123       1
 2      101      2017-04-01     456       2
 3      101      2017-04-02     789       1
 4      101      2017-04-02     103       2
 5      101      2017-04-03     192       1
 6      101      2017-04-03     112       2
```

As you can see, for iKey 101, the first date on the factProd table is 2017-04-01 (which correctly corresponds to the FirstFCDate column in Table1).

What I want to do is add a row to this factProd table for each date between 2017-01-13 (from the StartDate column) for each iKey + fcKey combination.

So the end result should look like this (ID is autogenerated):

```
 factProd
 ID     iKey     Date           pAmount   fcKey
 99     101      2017-01-13     0         1
 100    101      2017-01-13     0         2
 101    101      2017-01-14     0         1
 102    101      2017-01-14     0         2 
 103    101      2017-01-15     0         1
 104    101      2017-01-15     0         2
 ...    ...       ...           ...      ...
 199    101      2017-03-31     0         1
 200    101      2017-03-31     0         2

 1      101      2017-04-01     123       1
 2      101      2017-04-01     456       2
 3      101      2017-04-02     789       1
 4      101      2017-04-02     103       2
 5      101      2017-04-03     192       1
 6      101      2017-04-03     112       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James,

You may find it helpful to build a CTE table with one row for all of the possible dates between a range (i.e. MIN and MAX dates from your fact table), and then LEFT JOIN to it to find missing dates. You may also want to consider INSERTING into your fact table using LEFT JOIN, IS NULL logic, to get the missing days added. Your scenario is a bit more complex than only that, but it may lead you down a good path. Here is some code to build that table, virtually:

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime
DECLARE @ToDate datetime
SET @FromDate = '1/1/2017'
SET @ToDate = '1/1/2018';
WITH DayTable AS (SELECT CAST(@FromDate AS DATETIME) AS theDate UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, theDate) FROM DayTable s  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, theDate) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATETIME))
SELECT * FROM DayTable
OPTION 
(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Kindest regards...